# What does ... mean when coming directly after a slice?

Tags: go

What does `...` mean in this context in Go?

```
ids = append(ids[:index], ids[index+1:]...)
```

I have read this great Q&A: 
[Do three dots (which is called wildcard?) contain multiple meanings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340379/do-three-dots-which-is-called-wildcard-contain-multiple-meanings)

about what ... means in some situations, but I don't understand what it means in the situation above.

Comment: The three dots is called an "ellipsis". The question you linked directly answers you question. The other answer is kind of needlessly wordy, what what about it don't you understand?

Comment: TL;DR: assume `a := []int{1,2,3}` -- then `do(a...)` is equivalent to `do(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dot dot dot in golang. interface with empty braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669720/dot-dot-dot-in-golang-interface-with-empty-braces)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some languages (C, Python, ...) accept *variadic arguments*. Basically, you allow the client of a function to pass *a number* of arguments, without specifying how many. Since the function will still need to process these arguments one way or another, they are usually converted to a collection of some sort. For instance, in Python:

```
def foo(x, *args): # * is used for variadic arguments
    return len(args)

>>> foo(1)  # Passed the required argument, but no varargs
0 
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)  # Passed the required, plus two variadic arguments
2
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) # required + 5 args, etc...
5
```

Now one obvious problem of that approach is that *a number of arguments* is quite a fuzzy concept as far as types are concerned. C uses pointers, Python doesn't really care about types that much in the first place, and Go takes the decision of restricting it to a specified case: you pass [a slice of a given type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

This is nice because it lets the type-system do its thing, while still being quite flexible (in particular, the type in question can be an interface, so you can pass different 'actual types' as long as the function knows how to process these.

The typical example would be the [Command function](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command), which executes a program, passing it *some arguments*:

```
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
```

It makes a lot of sense here, but recall that variadic arguments are just a *convenient way to pass slices*. You could have the exact same API with:

```
func Command(name string, args []string) *Cmd
```

The only advantage of the first is that it lets you pass no argument, one argument, several... without having to build the slice yourself.

### What about your question then ?

Sometimes, you *do* have a slice, but need to call a variadic function. But if you do it naively:

```
my_args_slice := []string{"foo", "bar"}
cmd := Command("myprogram", my_args_slice)
```

The compiler will complain that it expects string(s), but got a slice instead ! What you want to tell it is that it doesn't have to 'build the slice in the back', because you have a slice already. You do that by using this ellipsis:

```
my_args_slice := []string{"foo", "bar"}
cmd := Command("myprogram", my_args_slice...) // <- Interpret that as strings
```

The `append` function, despite being built-in and special, [follows the same rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices). You can append zero, one, or more elements to the slice. If you want to concatenate slices (i.e. you have a 'slice of arguments' already), you similarly use the ellipsis to make it use it directly.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained

Answer (score 2):

It unpacks slice.

`ids[:index]` is a short form of `ids[0:index]`

`ids[index+1:]` is a short form of `ids[index+1:len(ids)-1]`

So, your example `ids = append(ids[:index], ids[index+1:]...)` translates to

```
//pseudocode
ids = append(ids[0:index], ids[index+1], ids[index+2], ids[index+3], ..., ids[len(ids)-2], ids[len(ids)-1])
```

Comment: You could think about it that way, but it reality it assigns the slice directly to the variadic slice in the arguments, which is much more efficient.

Comment: It's not "unpacking". Rather, it's close to "bypassing". That pseudocode is *not* equivalent to using `...`(ellipsis). As @JimB commented, if they are equivalent, a new slice with a **different** array should be made, but it's not. The slice inside of the `append` function points to the **same** underlying array.

Comment: @starriet
why should it be different array?
https://go.dev/play/p/IbdYeAJD1su
different slice, same underlying array

Comment: @Darigaaz Great example, but it's not related to what I mentioned above. What I'm saying is the parameter *within* the variadic function(`append`, in this case), not the returned slice of `append`. In your playground code, the first `append` creates a new slice with a *new* underlying array and then copies the elements to the array of the 1st input slice. But the second `append` does *not* create a new array. It just uses the existing underlying array and copies the elements to the array of the 1st input slice. So, these two returned slices look the same but the function works differently.

Comment: @starriet no, it is not. check the output. its the same `[1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 9] [1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]`  (4 is missing in original `a` slice) for both cases meaning 1st example does not create new underlying array.
If it was the case output would be  `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] [1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]`  (4 is still there).
Both examples works the same way and have nothing to do with semantics, only `len` and `cap` of "original" slice and number of elements to append matters.

Comment: @Darigaaz Yes, I totally understand what your code is trying to show(I think it's a very good example to understand slice). But, again, that's *not* related to what I'm talking about. You're talking about the **return** value. I'm talking about the parameter **within** the variadic function. Think about it: what are you going to do *inside* of the variadic function 1) if you got multiple inputs. 2) if you got a slice(this is the case when `...` is used). I'm talking about "under the hood" stuff :)

Comment: @Darigaaz [this code example](https://go.dev/play/p/xSqPD2Y3rBP) will clarify everything. You will easily understand why it is **not "unpacking"**. Please check it out. P.S. I didn't downvote your answer. All these answers and comments should be respected. Enjoyed the discussion!